# How to add "ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.getActivity" to an application?

Tags: android, parse-platform

In which file of an application do I need to add `getActivity` method of `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

If you followed the documentation for an existing project like me, this is deprecated:

PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, YourActivity.class);

This works to me:

Implement your receiver and extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver class.

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //To track "App Opens"
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);

        //Here is data you sent
        Log.i(tag, intent.getExtras().getString( "com.parse.Data" ));

        Intent i = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Then, in your AndroidManifest.xml, (Instead of using ParsePushBroadcastReceiver)

```
<receiver
    android:name="your.package.name.Receiver"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should add it to the class that extends the ParsePushBroadcastReceiver e.g.

```
public class YourBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

  ....
  protected Activity getActivity(Context context, Intent intent) {
    return yourActivity; // the activity that shows up 
  }
  ....

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is that I need to open another activity when a push notification is clicked. I read that I need to modify getActivity method of ParsePushBroadcastReceiver but how can this be done in the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

Write your on Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver and your activity with the help of below code.

```
public class ParsePushReciever extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Push", "Clicked");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Note: Your activity must be a launcher activity.