# Android ParsePushBroadcastReceiver in Xamarin

Tags: java, c#, android, parse-platform, xamarin.android

I am busy "recreating" an app written in Android Java to Xamarin C#

I need to extend the one class to `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` available in the `Parse` library found on NuGet and be able to override the `OnReceive` method. In java the library is extendable as seen in countless StackOverflow questions but in Xamarin, the class is sealed and can not be extended.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26180181/1876355

[How to add "ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.getActivity" to an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574363/how-to-add-parsepushbroadcastreceiver-getactivity-to-an-application)

I can not figure out how to go forward with this issue as there is existing code which needs to be executed in the `OnReceive` method.

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: Looks like this bug has already been reported https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like a bug](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/152)

Maybe you could re-create the class for now then replace when a future version of the Parse library is released?

```
namespace WorkAround.Parse 
{
    [Register("parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver")]
    public class ParsePushBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver 
    {
        internal const string KeyPushData = "com.parse.Data";
        internal const string ActionGcmRegisterResponse = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION";
        internal const string ActionGcmReceive = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE";
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            intent.SetClass(context, typeof(ParsePushService));
            ParseWakefulHelper.StartWakefulService(context, intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied your whole namespace, included `Parse;`, copied `Parse dot net SDK...Parse/Internal/Push/Android/ParseWakefulHelper.cs`'s contents into WorkAround.Parse and extended to `: WorkAround.Parse.ParsPush...` works perfectly

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! Just remember to fix this once the github issue is resolved :)